# android - How to display the previous status if you click on the cancel button of alert dialog multi choice items

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my application I am using alert dialog consists of multi choice items with positive and negative buttons. If you change the states of choice items, suppose if you click on ok button then next time dialog opens I want to show the update status. if you click on the cancel button then next time I want to show the previous status.Ok button is working fine but cancel button functionality is not working I tried but didn't get please can anybody help me.

Code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{

    switch (id) { 
    case DIALOG_MULTI_CHOICE:
         System.out.println("In dialog Choice_Checked:"+Arrays.toString(choice_checked));       
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.singlechoicelistitem))
            .setTitle("Bookmarking for")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(choice, choice_checked, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int index, boolean status) {                                      
                    if(status)
                    {
                        choice_checked_dynamic[index] = true;
                    }    
                    else
                    {
                        choice_checked_dynamic[index] = false;
                    }
                }                   
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {                       
                    saveBookmarkAction();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      ((Builder) dialog).setMultiChoiceItems(choice, choice_checked, null);
                      ((Builder) dialog).create();                                          
                }
            })
           .create();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by update status? What exactly does the status contain

Comment: My alert dialog have multi choice items. Initially i am displaying some items have selected in dialog. if you change that selection and click on ok button then next time u r opening the dialog i need to display the items based on changes. suppose click on the cancel button then i need to display the initiall display. i think it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If your previous state is an activity, then on onClick of cancel button, intent to previous activity else mere keeping the onClick function blank will do the trick of staying in the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

place dialog.cancel in negative button code

```
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

on click on cancel button you need to save the default settings.

create a method to set default setting and call that method onclick of cancel button

### Sample Code

```
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                       saveDefaultSettings(); //this method sets the default settings of tha app                                    
                }
            })
```

Comment: How to set the default settings? means how to update the status using which method?